# How can I find $f'(0)$ of this function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to find $f'(0)$ if $$f(x)={x^2\sin x-\cos\left(3x\right)\over e^{-3x}+1}$$

How do I do this? When I tried using the quotient rule it became messy very quickly so I thought that there must be another way.

Comment: I do not think it is hard to just derivate it

Comment: I got $-\frac{3}{4}$

Comment: Okay somebody help me as I'm going insane. Wolfram agrees that the derivative is $-3/4$. Using directly the definition (which I thought was going to be easier ) I get $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{ f(h) - f(0)}{h}$$. But $f(0) = -1/2$, and imputing that limit on wolfram returns $\pm \infty$

Comment: @grace You should use the definition of the derivative in case there is an indeterminate form ,i.e. the value of $x$ falls outside the domain of the given function. That is not the case here. So just apply the Quotient Rule and go through the rudiments of the algebra as Mathlove did

Comment: @imranfat That was actually me :P Anyhow I can use the definition of derivative if I want to, the point is that I can't find the error of why that limit does not yield $-3/4$! :)

Comment: Sorry Grace. Well Ant, you can use the definition, but perhaps could you  show where you went wrong then?...Of course we would expect the same answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x)=e^{-3x}+1,h(x)=x^2\sin x-\cos(3x)$. Here, we have $g(0)=2,h(0)=-1$.

Then, since we have
$$g'(x)=-3e^{-3x}$$
$$h'(x)=2x\sin x+x^2\cos x+3\sin(3x),$$
we have
$$g'(0)=-3,\ \ \ \ h'(0)=0.$$
Hence, we have
$$f'(0)=\frac{h'(0)g(0)-h(0)g'(0)}{(g(0))^2}=\frac{0-(-1)\cdot (-3)}{2^2}=-\frac 34.$$

Comment: How did you get the answer for $h'(x)$?

Comment: @Grace: $(x^2\sin x)'=(x^2)'\sin x+x^2(\sin x)'$. I hope this helps.